# Execute JavaScript in browser using Selenium + JavaScript or WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After whole lot of search for many days I am asking for help here.

We have a setup where we are using javascript + selenium(webdriverjs).

We want to pass data in the browser which is opened via selenium.
putting it simply, we want to execute any kind of javascript in the browser.

In java+selenium, we have JavaScriptExecutor class which does this thing.
In javascript+selenium I am not able to find any thing similar to it.

I have experimented with driver.executeJavaScript and driver.executeScript. But that does not work.

Please help.

Note: I can't use protractor in my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you go an example
protractor

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
```

async execution

```
browser.executeAsyncScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
```

for webdriver js or other framework try with

```
driver.executeScript()
```

Comment: browser is available only with protractor as far as I know. I can't use protractor.

Comment: try with driver

Comment: ok it worked. I had tried this before. My colleague was able to see it working but I couldn't. Problem was I was executing this inside a promise and for some reason it wasn't working. `const promise = driver.get('https://google.co.in/');
        promise.then(function() {
        driver.executeScript('window.abc="pramod";');
    }` After I removed it from promise and moved it above promise then it started working.