# Selenium "Element click is not clickable at point (52, 346). Other element would receive the click using" nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium

After resolve the wait and click problem I'm facing this one:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
"ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted-bar-item icon-transfer">...</button> is not clickable at point (52, 346). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ut-".`

How can we "implicit" click and ignore this kind of message?

the code to wait and click is as follow:

```
  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//button[text()='Transfers']")),15000);
  let btn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Transfers']"));
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(btn,15000));
  await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Transfers']")).click();
```

[code inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVtd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)... Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this line at the end `await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Transfers']")).click();` with this one:

```
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btn);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below line code/element which is throwing error

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Transfers']"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element );
```

javascriptexecutor of selenium will use javascript to click on element

protractor internally using selenium

Comment: what is this element on "element(by.id("myid"));"
I got a reference error because element is not defined...

Comment: updated my answer its an normal element, just pass your element in browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Element);

Comment: right... I don't have a "browser object"

my script is something like:

`
require('chromedriver');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var until = webdriver.until;
var By = webdriver.By;

async function myMain(){

    let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/');

    code to wait and click
}

myMain();
`

Comment: you are using protractor or webdriverIO or selenium webdriverjs?

Comment: see this , I guess you are using webdriverjs .. refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776654/execute-javascript-in-browser-using-selenium-javascript-or-webdriverjs

Comment: just change the java script parameter as per I have shown in answer

Comment: browser.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].click();", element );

Comment: Works like a charm <3