# Selenium Web Scraping a cryptocurrency website by automating a click that copies a text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots, cryptocurrency

So I am trying to get a text from this website https://dexscreener.com/solana/7bzzop3qb2zk3r7wqrzjs5fpeeergdy3hgzxxrn97aey
There is a button that when you click automatically copies the contact address of the cryptocurrency.
I use selenium. Why? Because the website has cloudflare antidetection and after a long time I finally found code that can bypass it.
So I need code that would be able to navigate to that page and click that button and print the pasted text.
[copy button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lezwj.png)

I only managed to write code for bypassing the cloudflare antibot detection, I tried using chatgpt to write me the code for getting the text but I keep getting errors.
I am not that experienced with coding though.

Here is the code:

```py
from time import sleep
from DrissionPage import ChromiumPage
p = ChromiumPage()
p.get('https://dexscreener.com/')

sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to click that button with selenium, then read the contents from clipboard. I assume you know how to click or were able to do it? Then your only challenge should be about how to read the clipboard contents?

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
value = root.clipboard_get()
```

You can use this if the browser is running locally and you have only one instance running. Otherwise, you can try [executing javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776654/execute-javascript-in-browser-using-selenium-javascript-or-webdriverjs) that returns the clipboard value (haven't tried this myself).

```js
try {
  return await navigator.clipboard.readText();
} catch (err) {
  return "";
}
```